# Verilog, Is this statement interpreted as I expect?

Tags: verilog

I've a verilog design where there's this line:

```
assign rb = (r == 0) ? 0 : (r == 01) ? g & t : (r == 10) ? g : g|t;
```

`g,t` are 1 bit values,`r` is a two bits value and `rb` is 1 bit.

I'm not a big expert in verilog, but I was wondering if such line is equivalent to

```
assign rb = (r == 2'b00) ? 0 : (r == 2'b01) ? g & t : (r == 2'b10) ? g : g|t;
```

Is it? If yes is the second better than the first? It's worth noting that the code compiles in the first case, and the output of the whole design outputs what I do expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Verilog standard defines that a number without a base is always an integer. Taking this into account, your third comparison is checking if `r` is "ten" and not "two" as in the second example. To make Verilog simulators interpret values as binary you will always need to include its base `'b`.

If your design is working in the same way in both examples, then I can only assume that `r` is never set to 2'b10. Otherwise, you would have different behaviors.

Answer (score 1):

The first line is making comparisons of `rb` with decimal numbers `0`, `1` and `10`, which are equivalent to `'b00`, `'b01` and `'b1010` in binary. In the third case, as the width is not matching on the two sides of the comparison operator, *zero filling* is occuring before the comparison, so two zeros will be appended to `r` on the left, so the equality will never be true.

Needless to say that the second line is doing a different thing (but probably the right one..)